# Using right pointer type, dont want to cast with void *

Tags: c, pointers, callback

Question regarding using the correct pointer type in my below code. When I try to initialize struct member function without type casting to void *, I got `“initialization from incompatible pointer type” warnings` ?

problem solved by typecasting but I want to use right pointer type instead of casting to void*.

**Code snippet:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef void (*set_id)(int id);
typedef void (*set_name)(char *name);

typedef struct prop {
    set_id *cb_setting_id;
    set_name *cb_setting_name;
}prop;


prop *setting_id(int id) {
    printf("ID:%d\n", id);  
}

prop *setting_name(char *in) {
    char *name;
    name = in;
    printf("Name:%s\n", name);
}
//Here type casted to void *, if not I get wrong pointer initalization 
//error
prop cb_prop = { .cb_setting_id=(void *)setting_id,     
                 .cb_setting_name=(void *)setting_name };

int main() {

    prop *cb_event; 
    cb_event = &cb_prop;

    cb_event->cb_setting_id = (void*)setting_id(2);
    cb_event->cb_setting_name = (void*)setting_name("/dev/ttyS1");

    return 0;   
}
```

**Without type casting, Warning are:**

```
struct_callback.c:25:33: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     prop cb_prop = { .cb_setting_id=setting_id,
                                     ^
struct_callback.c:25:33: note: (near initialization for ‘cb_prop.cb_setting_id’)
struct_callback.c:32:26: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  cb_event->cb_setting_id = setting_id(2);
```

Comment: Are members of the struct `prop` supposed to be data or function pointers? It's unclear what you are trying to store there.

Comment: Also, please explain why you are using different return types for function pointer typedefs and actual functions? (typedef returns `void`, but functions return `prop*`)

Comment: these two `typedef` statements are declaring functions that return `void`, Not what you want. I.E. these statements: `typedef void (*set_id)(int id);
typedef void (*set_name)(char *name);`  should be:  `typedef prop *(*set_id)(int);` and `typedef  prop *(*set_name)(char *);`  Then when calling those functions via the pointers, use the actual returned variable and the actual parameter value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the definition of e.g. the `set_id` type alias, it is a pointer to a function taking an `int` argument and not returning anything. Then compare it with the `setting_id` function, which is a function that takes an `int` arguments and ***returns a pointer to `prop`***. Those two types are not compatible. It's made even worse because the `setting_id` function is declared to return a pointer to `prop` but doesn't actually return anything.

And not only that, but the members in the structure are pointers to e.g. `set_id` which means that `cb_setting_id` is a pointer to a *pointer* to a function.

Later on you do

```
cb_event->cb_setting_id = (void*)setting_id(2);
```

This is wrong because it *calls* the `setting_id` function, and tries to assign the returned value to `cb_event->cb_setting_id`. But the `setting_id` function doesn't return anything.

The solution to the first problem is to make sure that both the `set_id` type and the function `setting_id` are equal.

The solution to the second problem is to not declare the members are pointers (since they already are), or by changing `set_id` to not be a pointer.

The solution to the third problem is to remove those lines, since the the first two solutions should solve the initial initialization of the `cb_prop` structure.

Comment: Your correct, I thought If I dont return anything from my functions then it will void. Actually function returns the pointer to struct. Thanks, now I know the right usage.

Answer (score 1):

The types you're assigning to are incompatible.

The function `setting_id` is of type `prop *(*)(int)`, but the `cb_setting_id` field is of type `void (*)(int)`.  Simiarly for `setting_name`.

You need to change the typedef to match the function.  Also, you have one extra level of indirection in your struct definition than you need.

```
typedef struct prop prop;

typedef prop *(*set_id)(int);
typedef prop *(*set_name)(char *);

struct prop {
    set_id cb_setting_id;
    set_name cb_setting_name;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your function pointer typedef does not match the actual functions, because you use different return types. But here you hide the pointer syntax behind a typedef:

```
typedef void (*set_id)(int id);
typedef void (*set_name)(char *name);
```

Therefore, these become pointer-to-function-pointer:

```
set_id *cb_setting_id;
set_name *cb_setting_name;
```

That's not what you want. Simply change the typedefs to:

```
typedef prop* set_id (int id);
typedef prop* set_name (char *in);
```

---

Please note that you are not allowed to cast a function pointer to/from a `void*`. Void pointers assume object pointers, not function pointers. So casting a function pointer to `void*` results in an invalid pointer conversion.